# Julia and Bash - Julia's shell mode doesn't execute ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bashrc)

Tags: bash, shell, console, julia

In all current versions of Julia, shell mode, when you type ";" in julia console, doesn't execute any of the code placed in my ~/.bash_profile, whereas my normal bash terminal does execute them.

If possible, how can I make the shell mode of Julia execute parts of my .bash_profile file, if not, will it be available in future Julia versions ?

I run my bash terminal in MacOS Mojave and here is a sample of code I have in my bash_profile :

```
alias ls='ls -GFh'
function d() {
    cd "$@"
    ls
}
```

So I can use "d" in my normal terminal but I can't use it in shell mode in Julia.

Comment: There is a high chance that using `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I don't think it's the problem, I did what KMZ said in his answer and I also tried to move everything in my ```.bash_profile``` to my ```.bashrc``` and delete the first one, it still didn't work. (Work for normal bash mode but doesn't work for Julia's shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is only ready when bash is started as a login shell (e.g. using `--login` CLI option). Apparently Julia starts bash as a normal (non-login) shell, in which case bash will only read `.bashrc` file.

To keep things relatively simple, you should probably move the code you want to always be executed into `.bashrc`, and then source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` like this:

```sh
[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did what you suggest, my bash still execute the commands I want, however, it doesn't seem to work in Julia's shell as I still get : ```/usr/local/bin/bash: d: command not found``` inside of it. So I can't choose your answer

Comment: @J.Khamphousone: can you please provide your `.bashrc`? remove all sensitive bits before posting if necessary...

Comment: @J.Khamphousone: ok, so if `.bashrc` doesn't seem to be used by shell, it's because of one of two things: either Julia doesn't really execute bash, or something stranger happens (e.g. Bash is started in `sh` compatibility mode). Let's figure this out together!

Comment: @J.Khamphousone: To find out what happens, go to shell mode from Julia and do this:
- Run `ps -u $USER` to make sure Julia does start `bash`, not `sh`;
- Check the following env.variables: `$SHELL`, `$-`, `$PS1`, `$BASH_ENV` -- these will give us more info about the mode Bash starts in;
- check you environment by running `env` and `set`. It is possible that function d() doesn't get passed down to subshells, which you fix with `export -f d dE dM2`.

Comment: That may sound crazy but none of your commands work in Julia terminal : `ps -u $USER` returns `ERROR: UndefVarError: USER not defined`, and `$SHELL` returns the same error. Actually they all returns this same error. Those commands are working ir regular terminal. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @J.Khamphousone: from what you posted it looks like Julia shell is not a real Bash shell. you can still check the process list using the following command: `ps -jH -u $(whoami)`, it should list a tree of all processes of your user. Look at what has been started by Julia to find out which shell it actually is.

Comment: @J.Khamphousone: also, the error message `UndefVarError` is certainly coming from Julia, which means that your commands are not interpreted by the actual bash. It looks like you won't be able to use anything that you defined in your bash startup files. The workaround is most likely to rewrite your aliases/functions in Julia.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm on MacOS and `ps -jH -u $(whoami)` returns me : `ps: illegal option -- H`

Comment: @J.Khamphousone: I can't test the actual MacOS syntax right now, but my idea was to show a process tree for your user, so that we can actually see if the actual bash gets started interactively by Julia, or does Julia "fake" the shell and only passes the commands you enter to one-off forked bash. It looks like the latter is the case so far: no typical bash variables available, Julia-produced error messages, and no profile interpretation.

Comment: Okay you can add this to your answer so I accept it if you want ;)